# Google Maps Javascript API v3 Troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, google-maps

So my code doesn't seem to work. It doesn't say invalid key or anything. It's just blank. Could you please look at my code to find the problem with it? Thank you.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEYDOESNTDISPLAYERRORS&sensor=false"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.0442, 9.9116);
            var settings = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                navigationControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; margin: auto;">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings variable doesn't have a closing bracket. The settings variable also isn't in the same scope as the global call to instantiate the map - even if it was, the map variable instantiation would take place before initialize() is called.  Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.0442, 9.9116);
        var settings = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);
    };

</script>
```